# Problem with installing vote_fu_rails_3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, vote

I'm trying to install the vote_fu_rails_3 gem for rails 3. I ran the command:

```
    $ rails plugin install git://github.com/vshvedov/vote_fu_rails_3.git
```

which I found here:

https://github.com/vshvedov/vote_fu_rails_3

no changes were made to the project and I got this error when after running the command:

```
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands/plugin.rb:
    277:in `<top (required)>': Commands is not a module (TypeError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_          
    support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_
    support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_
    support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_
    support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_
    support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_
    support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/comman
    ds.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It says Commands is not a module. Can anyone help? I'm running on Windows 7. I really appreciate it, thanks.